# Centering div in modal window

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox in my modal window. But it doesn't vertically center.

```
.menu-wrapper {
 display: flex;  
align-items: center; 
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;       
}
 .menu-window {
display: flex;
background:white;
margin: auto;
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/TsarS/rponj88t/)

Comment: It does seem center to me if I remove `display: none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using `display:flex` initially in `menu-wrapper` then you need to write `topMenuWindow.style.display = (topMenuWindow.style.display === "flex") ? "none" : "flex";` instead of `topMenuWindow.style.display = (topMenuWindow.style.display === "flex") ? "none" : "block";`

```js
(function() {
  var topMenuButton = document.querySelector("#menu_button");
  var topMenuWindow = document.querySelector('#topMenuWindow');

  topMenuButton.addEventListener('click', topMenuButtonChange);

  function topMenuButtonChange() {
    topMenuShow();
  }

  function topMenuShow() {
    topMenuWindow.style.display = (topMenuWindow.style.display === "flex") ? "none" : "flex";
  }



})();
```

```css
.menu-button {
  color: red;
  z-index: 10;
}
.menu-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: none;
}
.menu-window {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu__button" id="menu_button">open modal</div>

<div class="menu-wrapper" id="topMenuWindow">
  <div class="menu-window">
    CONTENT HERE
  </div>
</div>
```

> When your script works `display:flex` property of `main-wrapper` changes to `display:block` which is creating css errors.

Answer (score 1):

When you open modal the `display` propiety changes to `block`. Set the display to `flex`:

```
function topMenuShow() {
    topMenuWindow.style.display = (topMenuWindow.style.display === "flex") ? "none" : "flex";
}
```

Comment: @Gaurav Aggarwal answer a few seconds before me, the accepted check should be for him

Comment: i changed. Thank you

Comment: This is only fair  ;)

Answer (score 1):

this happens because after you click , `.menu-wrapper` has `display:block` . to vertically align on center you need to have `display:flex` so change `block` to `flex` in your JS :

```
function topMenuShow() {
    topMenuWindow.style.display = (topMenuWindow.style.display === "flex") ? "none" : "flex";
}
```

**see here : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/rj13bur7/)**

let me know if this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
Do you need like this:
you can refer a link:https://jsfiddle.net/rponj88t/2/
Html:
                <div class="menu__button" id="menu_button">open modal</div>               

            <div class="menu-wrapper" id="topMenuWindow">
                <div class="menu-window">
                    <centre>CONTENT HERE</centre>
                </div>
            </div>
Css:
.menu-button {
  color:red;
  z-index:10;
}
.menu-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    display: none;
}
.menu-window {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    background:white;
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-text:centre;
    text-align:centre;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:normal;
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-10%)
}
Js:
(function () {
   var topMenuButton = document.querySelector("#menu_button");
   var topMenuWindow = document.querySelector('#topMenuWindow');

    topMenuButton.addEventListener('click', topMenuButtonChange);

    function topMenuButtonChange() {       
       topMenuShow();
    }

    function topMenuShow() {
        topMenuWindow.style.display = (topMenuWindow.style.display === "flex") ? "none" : "block";
    }



})();
```